# How mount several directories on one mount point? (e.g. SD card)

Tags: mount

I have a plug computer with 512MB internal storage (NAND) and a SD card slot with an 8GB SD card, currently. The plug computer runs Ubuntu 9.04 (Jaunty), and I plan to use it mainly as a webserver.

As I have limited storage internally I want to move all directories potentially growing in size to the SD card (e.g. */var*, */srv*, */opt*). But is it possible to mount more than one directory onto the SD card?

What could a solution look like that doesn't play tricks with symlinks? Do I have to split the SD card into several partitions and mount them separately? Would be nice to know whether there is a solution that allows me to have a single, continuous place of storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **bind mount** allows you to mount a directory somewhere else in the file structure.

```
mount --bind /var/volumes/srv /srv
```

See the `mount(8)` man page for more details.

Comment: That's what my _/etc/fstab_ looks like for mounting the SD card and binding some directories to it:  
    /dev/mmcblk0p1              /media/sdcard   auto    defaults        0 0  
    /media/sdcard/opt   /opt            none    bind  
    /media/sdcard/srv   /srv            none    bind

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped, but `/media` would be the wrong place. Put it under `/mnt` instead.

Comment: Why? Aren't removable devices always (auto)mounted in `/media/<volume_name>`? What's wrong with it, can you explain? This leaves me `/mnt` free for manual mounts.

Comment: Indeed, `/media` is intended for automounts. However, you're putting system volumes on the card, therefore it's inappropriate to consider it an automount.